# Updating UI before running an async operation

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous

I'm trying to update my UI component before an async operation but the UI updates after the execution of the async Task. The following code is executed upon a button press:

```
  Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => { changeButtonToUnFollow(); });

  var friends = dbr.GetFollowers(user);
  var friendship = friends.Where(f => f.UserName == loggedUser && f.Friend_UserName == user).FirstOrDefault();
  dbr.DeleteFriend(friendship);
  followerscount.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(followerscount.Text) - 1).ToString();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                    {
                        await client.Follow(loggedUser, user, "true");
                    });
```

The method `changeButtonToUnFollow()` is what updates the UI component. The async method in the class "client" is defined as below:

```
    public async Task<string> Follow(string username, string friend_username, string unfriend)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync(GlobalVariables.host + "api/member/AddFriend/" + username + "/" + friend_username + "/" + unfriend).Result;

    return response.ToString();
}
```

How do I update the UI  before this async call is made?

Comment: try removing the `await` where you call `Follow`.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed. Same issue